# Getting a full response in Angular http Post request

Tags: angular

I am trying to get full response from a POST request. I have read how to get full response for a get request mentioned at the official site of angular.
[Angular http](https://angular.io/guide/http)

What it says is to add  `{ observe: 'response' }`. But it would work for a `get` request and not for `post` request. `post` request accepts 2-3 arguments, so I cannot send this as the 4th argument. Please have a look at my code and let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type':  'application/json'
        })
    };

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/Users/login', data, httpOptions, { observe: 'response' })
        .do( function(resp) {
            self.setSession(resp);
        });
```

This gives me an error as 4 arguments are not allowed.

**Edit**

The accepted answer seems to be not working now. I am getting the following

```
error:
error TS2345: Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; observe: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Types of property 'observe' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"body"'.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`observe` should be part of the `httpOptions` as a property.

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    }),
    observe: 'response'
};

 return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/Users/login', data, httpOptions)
   .do( function(resp) {
        self.setSession(resp);
 });
```

Comment: Yup, per documentation. https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post

Comment: Hi, please have a look at my edit. The answer seems to be not working.

Comment: Not working anymore (Angular 9) => Types of property 'observe' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"body"'.

Answer (score 8):

So: I needed to declare more explicitly type of httpOptions:

```
const httpOptions: { headers; observe; } = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
  }),
  observe: 'response'
};


return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/Users/login', data, httpOptions) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the options as following:

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    }),
    observe: 'response' as 'response'
};
```

Casting 'response' as 'response' will force picking the appropriate overload.