# Angular 6 HttpOptions, Observe Response, POST request

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am trying to create a POST request to do a login with angular 6. I also wish to observe the full response. I do not know how to fit all the information into the request. This is my code so far:

```
 loginRequest(userName: string, password: string, api: string = this.loginUrl): Observable<object> {

     const httpOptions = {
       headers: new HttpHeaders({
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }),
         observe: 'response'
      };
      var body = {
        user: userName,
        password: password
      }
      return this.http.post(api, body, httpOptions)
   }
```

This actually appears to achieve what I want in my unit tests, but Visual Studio is showing an error in the third paramter of the post method. Would anyone be able to show me how to fit all this information into the request correctly?

many thanks.

**update**
I have just found this answer which describes the same solution but for some reason I am still getting the error https://stackoverflow.com/a/50989991/8896573

**solved**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47761516/8896573

Comment: *"Visual Studio is showing an error"* - what error?

Comment: probably related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45797513/angular4-http-httpclient-requestoptions

Comment: "Argument of type {headers: HttpHeaders; Observe: string} is not assignable to parameter of type '{Headers? : HttpHeaders | { [ header: string ]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht.."

Comment: @JoeyGough the error you pasted is incomplete, can you please paste the full error in the question as update? By the way, try to replace the initialization of `const httpOptions` with: `let httpOptions= new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type': 'application/json').set('observe': 'response');` and then change `return this.http.post(api, body, httpOptions)` with `return this.http.post(api, body, { httpOptions } )`. I am using "`let`" because Angular6 [wants immutable headers](https://medium.com/spektrakel-blog/angular-httpclient-enforces-immutability-dad161d8714b). Let me know if it works!

Comment: @Deadpool I cannot view the full error message. It trails off into three dots ... and I cannot copy. I tried your suggestion but it did not work. in `.set('Content-Type': 'application/json').set('observe': 'response');` it says it is expecting a ',' instead of ':' . It also says that "arguement of type {HttpOptions: HttpHeaders} is not assignable to type..... as above"

Comment: Oh... Sorry, I made a mistake! Try with `let httpOptions= new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json').set('observe', 'response');`. The new error is right, it was right with the "," instead of ":"! Let me know if it works. For the full error, give a look on the "Output" window of visual studio. It should be on the bottom of the Visual Studio Window. The full error should be listed in there, try with a CTRL+F search in that box searching for the text you pasted above

Comment: Still not working. in `return this.http.post(api, body, { httpOptions } )` it says that argument of type '{ HttpOptions: HtpHeaders} is not assignable to parament of type..... as above.  The expected shape of the parameters for a POST request is described here  https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post